# If there is one item left in inventory I get SQLSTATE ERROR

Tags: mysql

I have been straggiling with this over a month and I'm going to kill myself or close the business. Please help me.

In Magento 1.8 when a customer place an order and if that order contains a product that has  1 item left in product inventory the customers receives friendly message saying "there was an order with your order" but the order get through and payment would be taken. If there is two Item with the same product this does not happen. also it becomes out of stock but the inventory stays 1.

So, the error I get with Payment transaction failed e-mail is:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1499-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

1499 is product ID.

I enabled debug in mysql. and this is 'var/debug/pdo_mysql.log';

```
    EXCEPTION 
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4368-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'' in F:\Projects\html2\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 F:\Projects\html2\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 F:\Projects\html2\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Zend\Db\Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 F:\Projects\html2\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 F:\Projects\html2\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 F:\Projects\html2\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Indexer\Price\Default.php(564): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#7 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Indexer\Price\Default.php(142): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default->_movePriceDataToIndexTable()
#8 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Indexer\Price.php(315): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default->reindexEntity(Array)
#9 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Indexer\Price.php(246): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexProductIds(Array)
#10 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Indexer\Abstract.php(163): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->catalogProductMassAction(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Event))
#11 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Indexer\Price.php(300): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->callEventHandler(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Event))
#12 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Indexer\Abstract.php(103): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Price->_processEvent(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Event))
#13 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Process.php(282): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->processEvent(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Event))
#14 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Process.php(384): Mage_Index_Model_Process->processEvent(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Event))
#15 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Process.php(360): Mage_Index_Model_Process->_processEventsCollection(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Event_Collection))
#16 [internal function]: Mage_Index_Model_Process->indexEvents('catalog_product', 'mass_action')
#17 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Indexer.php(378): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#18 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Indexer.php(223): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer->_runAll('indexEvents', Array)
#19 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Observer.php(983): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer->indexEvents('catalog_product', 'mass_action')
#20 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1338): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer->reindexProductsMassAction(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#21 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer), 'reindexProducts...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#22 F:\Projects\html2\app\Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('end_process_eve...', Array)
#23 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Indexer.php(334): Mage::dispatchEvent('end_process_eve...')
#24 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item.php(792): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer->processEntityAction(Object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item), 'cataloginventor...', 'save')
#25 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(319): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item->_afterSave()
#26 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Observer.php(746): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#27 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1338): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer->reindexQuoteInventory(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#28 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer), 'reindexQuoteInv...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#29 F:\Projects\html2\app\Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_model_ser...', Array)
#30 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Service\Quote.php(191): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_model_ser...', Array)
#31 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Service\Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#32 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage.php(785): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#33 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php(579): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#34 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#35 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#36 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#37 F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#38 F:\Projects\html2\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#39 F:\Projects\html2\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#40 {main}
```

things that I have done;
clean all the log files
remove tax classes
clean cahches

edit: after the comment bellow the system log is this:

```
2014-06-07T12:14:50+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage\Realex\Model\Remote.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in F:\Projects\html2\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93
2014-06-07T12:14:50+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage\Realex\Model\Remote.php' for inclusion (include_path='F:\Projects\html2\app\code\local;F:\Projects\html2\app\code\community;F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core;F:\Projects\html2\lib;.;F:\Projects\xampp\php\PEAR')  in F:\Projects\html2\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93
2014-06-07T12:14:52+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference  in F:\Projects\html2\app\design\frontend\magma\default\template\directory\currency-top.phtml on line 5
2014-06-07T12:15:04+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage\Realex\Model\Remote.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in F:\Projects\html2\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93
2014-06-07T12:15:04+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage\Realex\Model\Remote.php' for inclusion (include_path='F:\Projects\html2\app\code\local;F:\Projects\html2\app\code\community;F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core;F:\Projects\html2\lib;.;F:\Projects\xampp\php\PEAR')  in F:\Projects\html2\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93
2014-06-07T12:15:04+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference  in F:\Projects\html2\app\design\frontend\magma\default\template\directory\currency-top.phtml on line 5
2014-06-07T12:15:14+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage\Realex\Model\Remote.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in F:\Projects\html2\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93
2014-06-07T12:15:14+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage\Realex\Model\Remote.php' for inclusion (include_path='F:\Projects\html2\app\code\local;F:\Projects\html2\app\code\community;F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core;F:\Projects\html2\lib;.;F:\Projects\xampp\php\PEAR')  in F:\Projects\html2\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93
```

Thank you

edit: error starts after this query in pdo_mysql.log

```
## 2014-06-08 19:10:41
## 1716 ## QUERY
SQL: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_tmp` SELECT `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`entity_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`customer_group_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`website_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`tax_class_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`orig_price` AS `price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`price` AS `final_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`min_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`max_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`tier_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`group_price` FROM `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`
```

edit2: 
 there is a problem with duplicated entity.

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_tmp` (
    `entity_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID',
    `customer_group_id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Group ID',
    `website_id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Website ID',
    `tax_class_id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Tax Class ID',
    `price` DECIMAL(12,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Price',
    `final_price` DECIMAL(12,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Final Price',
    `min_price` DECIMAL(12,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Min Price',
    `max_price` DECIMAL(12,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Max Price',
    `tier_price` DECIMAL(12,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Tier Price',
    `group_price` DECIMAL(12,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Group price',
    PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`, `customer_group_id`, `website_id`),
    INDEX `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRICE_TMP_CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID` (`customer_group_id`),
    INDEX `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRICE_TMP_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
    INDEX `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRICE_TMP_MIN_PRICE` (`min_price`)
)
```

as you see entity_id, customer_group_id and website_id are primary keys. one of them is being duplicated somehow and I don't know how to find that dublicated data. is it entity_id? or customer_group_id? and where is it coming from?
What I did was for now, I dropped this table and created without making entity_id, customer_group_id, website_id PRIMARY KEY.
Now it's working but I don't think it is a good idea at all.
Thank you.

Comment: Within F:\Projects\html2\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Indexer\Price\Default.php(142): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default->_movePriceDataToIndexTable()
you should do a Mage::log() on $select->getSelect() after it is set and let us know what the query is having an issue with.  Look in var/log/system.log to see what it says.

Comment: @user2045 thank you so much. I edited my question as the error very long. I could not write here. thanks. the error at the end.

Comment: I need you to add a Mage::log() line to the file i told you to please to see the full sql statement.

Comment: see my question. I edited I added it there is nothing displaying... only those codes. i don't even know if they are right.. @user2045

Comment: Please do 2 queries and add them to your answer:                   1) SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp WHERE entity_id LIKE '1499%'                                        2) SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_index_price_tmp WHERE entity_id LIKE '1499%'

Comment: 0 result. it seems when a order being placed these catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp tables feels up with entitiy_id, customer_group_id and website_id as well as others. then It is supposed to be empty. however something is duplicating here. these tables are usually empty anyway. there is some indexing problem I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a guess, and can be an alternate to your problem too.
What i think is
Your settings:

> Admin: Catalog > Manage products   Choose a product: inventory
>
> - Qty = Your quantity
> - Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock = 0
> - Stock availability: in stock

May not be proper:

There is a similar setting in admin also:

> Admin: System > Configuration   Inventory: Qty for Item's Status to
>
> Become Out of Stock = 0

Try checking these two configurations, this may be the cause.

Alternate:Change your settings to 1, for out of stock

> Admin: Catalog > Manage products   Choose a product: inventory
>
> - Qty = Your quantity
> - Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock = 1//Update this
> - Stock availability: in stock

This way whenever you have 1 product in inventory it will not be able to checkout, and you can resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what the SQL query is so you can locate the table with the duplicate keys.

You might try truncating `sales_flat_quote` and `sales_flat_quote_item` tables, as well as incrementing all the `increment_last_id` values in `eav_entity_store` by 10,000 or some large number.

Comment: it did not work.. do you think is there anything related to catalog_product_index_price_tmp table?

Comment: Why guess?  Follow the suggestions and get the full SQL query that's causing the error.  This will tell you which table is the culprit.

Comment: please see my question. I edited it.

Comment: Try truncating `catalog_product_index_price_tmp` and then reindexing prices.

Comment: I did that too..